# Creating ID column in Pandas based on Groupby of certain column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Having Pandas dataframe with one column like that:

[image]

I would like to create ID column based on groupby() logics of `time` column like this:

[image]

Know how to do that incrementally: using `index` as a column or using `groupby()` with `rank` function:

```
df['ID'] = df.groupby('time')['time'].rank(method='first')
```

But how can it be done using the requested way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the input you could make use of [`pd.factorize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html):

```
df['ID']=pd.factorize(df.time)[0]
print(df)

       time  ID
0  01.09.16   0
1  01.09.16   0
2  01.09.16   0
3  02.09.16   1
4  02.09.16   1
5  02.09.16   1
6  03.09.16   2
7  03.09.16   2
8  03.09.16   2
```